# How to search in google with Curl php

Tags: php, curl

i write this code in php
in localhost is work but in host not work

```
function cURL($url, $ref, $header, $cookie, $p){
    $ch =  curl_init();//start curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);            //curl Targeted URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);        //fake referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    
    if ($p) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
    }
    $result =  curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($result){
        return $result;
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}
```

use in index:

```
 $file = cURL('https://www.google.com/search?num=30&hl=en&q=phpscript','http://www.google.ru',0,0,null);
```

Comment: what doesn't work? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Google actively monitor and prevent scraping of their content...little bit ironic coming from the biggest scrapers of data in the world, but even if you get this to work, it will only do so for an extremely limited time. Take it from somebody who has tried.

Comment: Use a proxy to get past this

Comment: Please don't post signature links.

Answer (score 0):

Your host could be blocking bots(?) Simplified a little - but this works for me:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by CompuSolver.com.
 * User: Hank Castello
 * Date: 6/20/16
 * Time: 10:27 AM
 */
function curlGet($url, $header){
   $ch =  curl_init();//start curl
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);            //curl Targeted URL
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.8 [en] (Windows NT 5.1; U)');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

   $result =  curl_exec($ch);
   $httpResponse = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
$targetURL = 'https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=web+developers&oq=web+developers&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.1547.5649.0.6045.15.11.0.4.4.0.115.760.8j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..2.12.714.0..0i131j0i3.xUKoFB0hpKM';
$header = array('Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,bn-bn;q=0.3','Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5');
$responsePg = curlGet($targetURL, $header);
echo $responsePg;
```